# foreach() skipping first element in array

Tags: php, html

Trying to create a GPA Calculator. I have a form that submits to a php file and then stores all data from the form in a php array(). The calculator works great until I enter the same   value. I think this wont make sense until I show some pictures:

Here is the problem in an image:

[image: Error Scenario]

[image: Correct Scenario]

So in the first image I enter a A and then another A which outputs array(1) { [0]=> float(4.5) } when using var_dump()

And in the second image the var_dump() is array(2) { [0]=> float(4) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id7kF.png)=> float(3.5) }

It is skipping the first row in the first image... just in case A is supposed to equal 4.0 in REG and 4.5 in HONORS. It might be the array_combine()

Here is my php code:

```
//$_POST['grades'] for the grades <option> and $_POST['types'] for the type (REG, HONORS)
foreach(array_combine($_POST['grades'], $_POST['types']) as $code => $count)
{

    if ($code == "A")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 4.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 4.5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 5.0;
        }
    }
    else if ($code == "B")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 3.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 3.5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 4.0;
        }
    }
    else if ($code == "C")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 2.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 2.5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 3.0;
        }
    }
    else if ($code == "D")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 1.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 1.5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 2.0;
        }
    }
    else if ($code == "F")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 0.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = .5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 1.0;
        }
    }


}
```

It might be the whole foreach() statement that needs reworking... I am up to writing the logic again if anyone says so...

I don't want to clog up the question with code so if you absolutely need the html just ask and I will add in an edit.

EDIT: I am also thinking I need to rewrite the logic... I have never used array_combine() before... I just need to make sure the  corresponds with the related

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe a dump of `$_POST` will be helpful.

Comment: i think array combine is the probs.,first aray may contain same grade there fore it will be discarded .

Comment: Tried that got array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(1) "A" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "0" [4]=> string(1) "0" } for 'grades[]' and array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "REGULAR" [1]=> string(7) "REGULAR" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "0" [4]=> string(1) "0" } for 'types[]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this array and output look the VALUES "a" which becomes the key of the resultant array,
so if u want the full array to be combined with the key of first array then first array must kave unique values.

```
  <?php
    print_r(array_combine(Array('a','a','b'), Array(1,2,3)));
    ?>
    Returns:
    Array
    (
        [a] => 2
        [b] => 3
    )
```

solution (may not be the best )

```
foreach($_POST['grades'] as $KEY=>$code)
{
   $count  = $_POST['types'][$KEY];
   if ($code == "A")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 4.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 4.5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 5.0;
        }
    }
    else if ($code == "B")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 3.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 3.5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 4.0;
        }
    }
    else if ($code == "C")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 2.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 2.5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 3.0;
        }
    }
    else if ($code == "D")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 1.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 1.5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 2.0;
        }
    }
    else if ($code == "F")
    {
        if ($count == "REGULAR")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 0.0;
        }
        else if ($count == "HONORS")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = .5;
        }
        else if ($count == "COLLEGE")
        {
            $GradeArray[] = 1.0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So I am guessing don't use array_combine()... how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: -1. A Cartesian product will most definitely give the wrong results.

Comment: The revised code should work if both array indices are the same. Removed the -1.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate over two arrays (or more) you could consider using the [`MultipleIterator`](http://www.php.net/multipleiterator); it doesn't clobber array keys like `array_combine()` does.

You could also simplify your logic by using an array to define the scores of each grade / type combination:

```
$gradesToScores = array(
  'REGULAR' => array(
    'A' => 4.0, 'B' => 3.0, 'C' => 2.0, 'D' => 1.0, 'F' => 0.0,
  ),
  'HONORS' => array(
    'A' => 4.5, 'B' => 3.5, 'C' => 2.5, 'D' => 1.5, 'F' => 0.5,
  ),
  'COLLEGE' => array(
    'A' => 5.0, 'B' => 4.0, 'C' => 3.0, 'D' => 2.0, 'F' => 1.0,
  ),
);

$gradeItemIterator = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$gradeItemIterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['grades']), 'grade');
$gradeItemIterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['types']), 'type');

$gradeScores = array();

foreach ($gradeItemIterator as $gradeItem) {
  $gradeScores[] = $gradesToScores[$gradeItem['type']][$gradeItem['grade']];
}
```

Comment: I have never done this before, but it looks nicer... I tried it and used var dump on $gradeScores[] but got NULL values in var_dump()

Comment: @cipherous Realized I forgot to add a flag to the constructor; it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Arun on the reason for the behaviour. A possible solution would be:

```
$lookup = Array("A"=>4, "B"=>3, "C"=>2, "D"=>1, "F"=>0);

for ( $i=0; $i<count($_POST['grades']); $i++ ) {
    $temp = $lookup[ $_POST['grades'][$i] ];
    if ( $_POST['types'][$i] == "HONORS" ) {
        $temp += .5;
    }
    elseif ( $_POST['types'][$i] == "COLLEGE" ) {
        $temp += 1;
    }
    $GradeArray[] = $temp;
}
```

This assumes the count of `$_POST['grades']` and `$_POST['types']` to be equal - otherwise it will either cause an `undefined offset` notice or not address each value.

---

<strike>Regarding Arun's code: nesting the two loops will create N*M inner loop iterations - one for each combination of grade/type, clearly wrong in this case! We need to go through the arrays *in parallel*, as they are used to hold pair values.</strike>

---

<strike>@Jack: If I'm not mistaken, you need to swap `HONORS` and `COLLEGE` in your Array definition.</strike>

Comment: If you want to leave comments on another answer, you should use the "add comment" feature instead of updating your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me fine

```
$array = array('ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de');
$array = array_combine(range(1, count($array)), array_values($array));
print_r($array);
```